# how to create add minus button on my product in flutter?

Tags: flutter

May I know how to create a function that displays the value and have the button remove and add to the product list? I already create an icon button for remove and add to the screen but I do not have any clues on how to use the button.

GUI on application:

[image]

my aim is to have this kind of button:

[image]

my full code for this GUI:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'CartList.dart';
import 'bottom_navi_iconW.dart';
import 'globals.dart' as globals;

class SarapanPagi extends StatefulWidget {
  final List list;
  final int index;
  final String category;
  SarapanPagi({this.index,this.list,this.category});


  @override
  _SarapanPagiState createState() => _SarapanPagiState();

}

class _SarapanPagiState extends State<SarapanPagi> {



  Future<List> getData() async{

    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2/foodsystem/breakfastlist.php';
    var data = {
      'product_type': globals.jenisCategory,
      'product_owner': widget.list[widget.index]['restaurant_id'],
    };
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
    //final response= await http.get("http://10.0.2.2/foodsystem/getdata.php");
    return json.decode(response.body);}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            //Text("Restaurant's Owner Page"),
            Text(widget.list[widget.index]['restaurant_name'], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700), ),
          ],
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
        //automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),

      body:
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0, left: 5, right: 5),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            /*FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: (){
                return showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context){
                    return AlertDialog(
                      content: Text(
                          globals.jenisCategory
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),*/
            //SizedBox(height: 30,),
            Container(
              //decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 4), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              height: 627,
              child: FutureBuilder<List>(
                future: getData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

                  return snapshot.hasData ?
                  ItemList(list: snapshot.data,) :
                  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar:
      Container(
        height: 70,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: BottomNavIcon(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context)=> new CartListItem()),);
          },
          image: "troli.png",
          name: "CART",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends StatelessWidget {



  final List list;
  ItemList({this.list});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        //color: Colors.red.shade100,
        height: 627,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list==null ? 0 : list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i){
            return new Container(
              //decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 4), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              height: 250,
              child: new GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){},
                child: new Card(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom : 5.0),
                            child: Text(list[i]["product_name"], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              //Text(list[i]["product_name"], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "menulist/${list[i]['image']}",
                                  width: 150,
                                  height: 150,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, bottom: 0),
                                child:
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    //Text(list[i]["product_name"], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
                                    Text("Price RM : ${list[i]["product_price"]}", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        IconButton(
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                                            onPressed: (){},
                                            iconSize: 15,
                                        ),
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                                          onPressed: (){},
                                          iconSize: 15,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    RaisedButton(
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                                        color: Colors.red.shade300,
                                        child: Text("Add to Cart", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                        onPressed: (){},
                                    )
                                  ],

                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      /*ListTile(
                        title: Text(list[i]["product_name"], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
                        leading:
                        Image.asset(
                          "images/${list[i]['image']}",
                          width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text("Price RM : ${list[i]["product_price"]}", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                      ),*/
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to change it to StatefulWidget, since the UI interaction is rendered (changed price). Then something like

`onPressed: () => setState(() => list[i]["product_price"] += unitprice),`

will do